# Text disappears when I insert a hyperlink

Tags: java, android, layout, hyperlink

In my android project, whenever I insert an hyperlink in my text, the hyperlink works, but the rest of my text just disappears. The hyperlink is shown in the middle of the screen, there is no text visible around it, while I clearly have a lot of text written in my `strings.xml`.

This is a screenshot on how it looks like:
[image]

This is how it looks like in my Graphic layout. Underneath that text is the link:

[image]

This is my MainActivity code:

```
package com.example.rodekruis;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BWCActivity extends Activity {


     TextView HyperLink;
     Spanned Text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bwc);

        TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setClickable(true);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        String text = "<a href='https://www.rkz.nl/het_kinderbrandwondencentrum'> Kinderbrandwondencentrum </a>";
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));

    }

}
```

This is my layout activity code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.Bezoek" >



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo" 
        android:layout_gravity="left" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"/>


    <ScrollView
         android:id="@+id/scrollview"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="364dp" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="276dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_bwc"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />


</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

In my strings I just have a lot of text, it doesn't fit in my screen, that's why I have added a Scrollview. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `ScrollView` with this:

```
<ScrollView
         android:id="@+id/scrollview"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title_activity_bwc"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This puts the link on top of my screen. The other text is still not visible

Comment: Which other text you are saying about?

Comment: I'll edit my post with the graphic Layout that is shown in my project, to see what's the difference

Comment: That text. Underneath that text is the link, so that's why I have the scrollview in it. When you start the project you are able to scroll down to the link, if the text would be visible, which it is not.